# Associative algebra over the field of real numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Prove that the associative algebra without divisors of zero over the field $\mathbb R$ of dimension greater than 2 can not be commutative.

I'm new to this and I will be very grateful for your help!

Comment: The title is about the rational numbers, the body has the field of real numbers. Please, fix.

Comment: For example you can take the associative algebra of $2\times 2 $ real matrices .

Comment: I'm confused-$\Bbb R[x]$ is an infinite-dimensional associative algebra over $\Bbb R$, and it's commutative.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose that $A$ has a neutral element $1$, then $A$ is field. The only finite extension of $R$ is $C$.